# TreeList. How to make the columns to the right of the column that expands retain their width?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Treelist has 6 columns.
When I use the mouse to increase the width of the column number "1", all the columns to the right of the column "1" decrease their width.
In other words, if you expand a column, the remaining columns on the right are narrowed.

How to make the columns to the right of the column that expands retain their width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you don't want to auto resize of the columns? You can set the following options to restrict auto resize of the columns

```
treeList1.OptionsView.AutoWidth=false
```